# Unitarity violation in 2D conformal field theory (CFT)

Tags: conformal-field-theory, unitarity

Why if we have a 4 point function in 2D CFT on the plane with non-OPE singularities this would be a signal of unitarity violation?

Comment: Because in any configuration there is a channel in which the OPE expansion converges, and you can show regularity based on that. Convergence of OPE expansion follows quite rigorously from unitarity.